# How large can a sphere of water in low earth orbit get?

Tags: surface-tension, tidal-effect

Imagine that er have a large space station in low earth orbit, and inside that space station is a large sphere of water.
How large can that sphere of water get before tidal forces overwhelm surface tension and cohesion and tear it apart.

Comment: Are you asking how the [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit) is calculated for a liquid? It’s not clear what set of assumptions you wish to start with.

Comment: The sphere is at an altitude of 500km, inside a space station (so normal atmosphereic pressure and temperature.) Primary force holding it together is cohesion.

Comment: The question is misconstrued. To get cohesion and tidal forces to be significant on the same scale, you're going to need something much more dense than a planet.

Comment: https://www.theguardian.com/science/video/2014/nov/07/water-bubble-space-science-video That ball is stable, but if it were to big, Earth would pull it apart.